# Any advice translating NWD to SVF for down sizing?

Tags: autodesk-forge

When I translated 20 Mb sized NWD file, it gave me 200 Mb SVF file which is 10 times bigger than the original one.
I also checked properties.db file sizing 30 Mb but the SVF file is still bigger around 170 Mb.

Do you have any advice translating NWD to SVF for down sizing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Navisworks file is a data aggregator, so its own size does not necessarily reflect the data size of the model - you would need to include all dependencies as well. But as you describe your problem, I understand you got a single NWD file and no dependencies.

With Navisworks, there is still some data expanding when translating to SVF. Unless you really need them, you can tell the extractor to not include them. When translating to SVF or SVF2, there is a 'advanced' section to the payload which now accepts some [new parameters](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/job-POST/) listed below  (scroll to the SVF Attributes by Output Type). I would also recommend you to take a look to Kevin Vandecar' AU presentation on that subject at https://au.autodesk.com/.

By default all these new attributes are turned off which should make your SVF a minimum size. If this is not the case, please contact us and share the model so we can have a deeper look at the issue.

hiddenObjects - bool
An option to be specified when the input file type is Navisworks.
true: Extract hidden objects from the input file.
false: (Default) Do not extract hidden objects from the input file.

basicMaterialProperties - bool
An option to be specified when the input file type is Navisworks.
true: Extract properties for basic materials.
false: (Default) Do not extract properties for basic materials.

autodeskMaterialProperties - bool
An option to be specified when the input file type is Navisworks.
true: Extract properties for Autodesk materials.
false: (Default) Do not extract properties for Autodesk materials.

timelinerProperties - bool
An option to be specified when the input file type is Navisworks.
true: Extract timeliner properties.
false: (Default) Do not extract timeliner properties.

I do recommend using SVF2 format in your case to de-duplicate objects and save memory as much as possible.